# SQL server and STUFF with two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm facing a problem. I have two tables as below.

table 1

```
+----+------+  
| ks | keys |  
+----+------+  
|  11 | 1122|  
+----+------+  
|  12 | 2211|  
+----+------+  
|  13 | 2233|  
+----+------+  
|  14 | 3322|  
+----+------+
```

table 2

```
+----+--+-------+  
| Id | ks|codes|                 
+----+-----------+  
|  1 | 11  |aaaaa|  
+----+-----------+  
|  2 | 11  |bbbbb|  
+----+-----------+  
|  3 | 12  |aaaaa|  
+----+-----------+  
|  3 | 13  |ccccc|  
+----+-----------+  
|  4 | 12  |bbbbb|  
+----+-----------+
```

I tried to implement a following query in order to get my required output but did not work:

```
SELECT ks,
        STUFF (
                (SELECT ', ' + t2.codes as [text()]
                        from table2 as t2 where t1.ks = t2.ks FOR XML PATH('')
                ),1,1,'' 
               ) as "codes" 
from table1 t1
group by ks;
```

I get this table as result:

```
+----+------+  
| ks | codes|  
+----+------+  
| 11 | aaaa |  
+----+------+  
| 11 | bbbb |  
+----+------+  
| 12 | cccc |  
+----+------+  
| 12 | dddd |  
+----+------+
```

then this image below shows my required output:
[required result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkN1Y.jpg)

I did something wrong but I do not know what could be. Any chance someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: `table2` doesn't have a `ks`.

Comment: sorry, i've just edited table2 header @Yogesh Sharma

Comment: You cannot get that output from the query with the sample data you have shown.

Comment: may you help me @GordonLinoff

Comment: I commited a mistake, table1 has no code column. i fixed table1 header and data. i'm so sorry.

Comment: There is no `code` as `dddd` or `eeee` in table2. How do you expect them in the output?

Comment: I posted an image as required output. please, take a look at it.@AjayGupta

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I think you posted the wrong output.

```
Create table #tbl (ks int , codes varchar(10))  
Insert into #tbl values
 (11 ,'aaaa'),  
 (12 ,'bbbb'),  
 (13 ,'cccc'),  
 (14 ,'dddd')

Create table #tbl2 (id int, ks int , codes varchar(10))  
Insert into #tbl2 values
( 1 ,11 ,'aaaaa'),  
( 2 ,11 ,'bbbbb'),  
( 3 ,12 ,'aaaaa'),   
( 3 ,13 ,'ccccc'),   
( 4 ,12 ,'bbbbb')

with cte as
(Select t1.ks, t2.codes 
from #tbl t1 join #tbl2 t2 on t1.ks = t2.ks)
Select ks, STUFF(
                 (SELECT ',' + codes FROM cte c1 
                  where c1.ks = c2.ks FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, ''
                ) 
from cte c2 
group by ks
```

Output:

```
ks
11  aaaaa,bbbbb
12  aaaaa,bbbbb
13  ccccc
```

Comment: I'm upvoting because this pretty much demonstrates that the OP's original code works.

Comment: yes @Gordon Linoff, but considering that new tables relationship the code will not as I tested exhaustedly. many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say that I fully understand what is going on in your tables--especially given your output image appears to have no relation to your sample tables--but it looks like you want a comma-delimited list of sub-values from table2 that are associated with table1.

Here's a working example that I think addresses your need. You can use CROSS APPLY in these situations. Doing so allows you to return *all* values from table1 regardless of a matching record in table2.

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE ( [ks] INT, [code] VARCHAR(10) );
DECLARE @table2 TABLE ( [id] INT, [ks] INT, [code] VARCHAR(10) );

    -- populate table1 --
    INSERT INTO @table1 (
        [ks], [code]
    ) 
    VALUES
    ( 11, 'aaaa' )
    , ( 12, 'bbbb' )
    , ( 13, 'cccc' )
    , ( 14, 'dddd' );

    -- populate table two --
    INSERT INTO @table2 (
        [id], [ks], [code]
    )
    VALUES
    ( 1, 11, 'aaaaa' )
    , ( 2, 11, 'bbbbb' )
    , ( 3, 12, 'aaaaa' )
    , ( 3, 13, 'ccccc' )
    , ( 4, 12, 'bbbbb' );


    SELECT
        t1.ks, codes.codes
    FROM @table1 t1
    CROSS APPLY (

        SELECT (
            STUFF(
                ( SELECT ', ' + t2.code AS "text()" FROM @table2 t2 WHERE t2.ks = t1.ks FOR XML PATH ( '' ) )
                , 1, 2, ''
            )
        ) AS [codes]

    ) AS codes
    ORDER BY
        t1.ks;
```

Resulting Output:

```
ks  codes
11  aaaaa, bbbbb
12  aaaaa, bbbbb
13  ccccc
14  NULL
```

Comment: but considering that new tables relationship the code will not as I tested exhaustedly